# Export a website to an XML Page

Tags: php, javascript, python, xml, perl

I need to export a website(.html page) to a XML file. The website contains a table with some data which i require for using in my web project. The table in the website is formed using some javascript, so i cannot get the data by getting the page source. Please tell me how I can export the table in the website to a XML file using php/python/javascript/perl.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: this may not be relevant, but would [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) not help you?

Comment: I had no idea how to do it. Previously i used to get the source code of the site using a perl script but now i can't do anything. Please help.

Comment: you need a browser engine to load the page and deliver the html

Comment: @njzk2 — That is the other approach that could work. I would have recommended it, but the OP indicated the priority was on execution speed, which makes troelskn's recommendation to reverse engineer the code (which doesn't require a browser engine to be used by the program) the more suitable solution.

Comment: Manually, Web Developer Tools extension in Firefox will let you copy and paste *generated* code as well as source code. Assuming you've the legal right to scrape this website...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to reverse engineer the javascript code. Maybe it's making an ajax request to a service, that delivers the data as json. Use your browsers developer tools/network tab to see what's going on.

Comment: I need this to be done in a faster way. Only then will I get a desired output in my project. Won't the above solution take too much time to load?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT — No. It will take time to develop. It has the fastest execution time of any of the alternatives.